# I am having problems with my Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics card

Tags: drivers, graphics

What happened?

1. I installed ubuntu.
2. I installed xubuntu desktop.
3. I also installed the lubuntu desktop.
4. I think I upgraded my system after that.
5. The graphics on this page started to look bad (see [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZM1b.png) image) https://human.biodigital.com/view?id=4IPv&lang=en
6. I also started to see lines in some parts of my screen. Small lines.
7. I entered the page from a live version of Ubuntu. The graphics looked fine.
8. I reinstalled ubuntu. I did not format the disk. I just reinstalled it from a usb.
9. No more streaks and the page graphics looked fine.
10. The system updated itself.
11. When I restarted it again I saw the little lines and the page graphics looked bad again.
12. I have read that it may be a kernel issue. I used these ppa's but they had no effect.

Questions:

1. If I use linux mint will it fix the problem?
2. If I use an older version of ubuntu will it fix the problem?
3. What else can I do?

Comment: You've provided no release details; Mint is not Ubuntu or *flavor* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) thus off-topic here... so how can we help?   LTS releases offer two kernel stacks, but you didn't provide any details as to which you tried/used? or if you tried the other option available to you (drivers are strictly *kernel modules* hence kernel stack choice..)

Comment: Example, I QA-test on various boxes; I had a couple of thinkpads that are great on 18.04 using GA kernel, and were great too on HWE up till 18.04.4 or the 5.3 kernel... but they didn't like the 5.4/18.04.5 stack so graphics etc issues occur once upgraded.. The simplest fix is just use the GA kernel & issue is gone (for all Ubuntu & *flavors* too).  You however gave no specifics on what you tried, used, or when you upgraded (non-live) what changes that made (what did you install? you didn't say so it may have been a change like my example); quick & easy may be switching kernel stack).

Comment: Good evening:
Sorry I am a novice user. 
I update and add information about what happened to me:
1. I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS.
7. I entered the site from a live version of Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS. The graphics looked fine on the site.
8. Reinstall Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS. I did not format the disk. I just reinstalled it from a usb.
12. I used some PPAs. Sorry I can't find the web address. 

I have to add something else I have done in the last two hours:
I installed Ubuntu 21.04. The problem with graphics is the same.

Thank you very much for taking the time to answer me.

Comment: You weren't specific as to if you meant Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 or Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.2, as server defaults to the GA kernel (5.4) and Server defaults to HWE kernel (5.8) .. but I'm betting it's desktop (due to graphics). Using PPAs mean I can't help unless I know what PPAs you've used. PPAs are 3rd party *personal package archives* and they can turn your system into a non-Ubuntu so you need to be specific & careful with them - all security checks & fitness for purpose is on you, as they're not Ubuntu repositories.. (but 3rd party)

Comment: I found the information.
Step 12. From this address: https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu/updates. 
Use this command:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
sudo apt-get update
Note: I installed this PPA when I had installed on my machine ubuntu focal 20.04 desktop version.
Thank you.

Comment: @Ruzel... If it solved your problem, maybe you should post it in a detailed form as an answer... and then accept it when possible.